# How to detect only one click on gameobject using Ray

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I detect that a gameobject was clicked only one time, now I have this code

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click, casting ray");
            CastRay();
        }   
    }

protected void CastRay(){
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Infinity);
        if(hit){
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
```

and it detect a click but 12 times, i tried to add `wasClicked` bool but still detect 12 clicks. It possible to detect click only one time?

Comment: I think the Bool should have worked can I see how you added it.

Comment: `private bool wasClicked = false;


void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !wasClicked){
            wasClicked = true;
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click, casting ray");
            CastRay();
        }   
    }`

Comment: I think problem is with `Update()` but I dont know what other function could i use here

Comment: I'm going to look more but based on what I'm see on Unity Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html. your code should work even without the Bool. sorry I'm not much help I haven't used unity for a long time. Im guessing the `CastRay` happens 12 time two?

Comment: I tested code from Documentation in my project and it detects click once so it's seems that only in my script detects click 12 times, kinda weird

Comment: it's not by `castRay()` because i delete this for test and still detect click 12 times

Comment: Sometimes the debug/terminal like to show extra stuff. It could be showing how long the button press was for (12sec). feel free to test my theory. But if it works it works right :)

Comment: I pressed the mouse longer but still detects click 12 times, logs times are the same. Maybe it's like you said extra stuff. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Np. Sorry I couldn't be of much help for you

Comment: The code will detect click only once. But you can have multiple instances of the code running at the same time in your scene.

Comment: After restarting unity, at first click was detected 12 times, but next clicks (second, third etc.) is detect once so it's maybe was extra stuff. But how can I check that i have multiple instances of the code?